# Laravel Mail:: attach file only if not null

Tags: php, laravel, email, vue.js

Hi everybody I have a mail where the file field is nullable (not required) however because of this when I try to attach a null uploadFile I get the following error:

"message Undefined index: uploadFile"

My question is is there a nice laravel way to only attach the file to mail if it exists?

This is my mail build method:

```js
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ClientContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
    public $mailData;

    public function __construct($mailData)
    {
        $this->mailData = $mailData;
    }

    
    
    
    public function build()

    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.client-contact')
        ->from($this->mailData['sender'], $this->mailData['appName'])
        ->subject($this->mailData['subject'])
        ->attach($this->mailData['uploadFile'], ['as' => $this->mailData['fileName'], 'mime' => $this->mailData['mimeType']]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve this with a simple if statement, if file exists attach it.

```
public function build()

{
    $mail = $this->markdown('emails.client-contact')
        ->from($this->mailData['sender'], $this->mailData['appName'])
        ->subject($this->mailData['subject']);

    if (isset($this->mailData['uploadFile'])) {\
        $mail = $mail->attach($this->mailData['uploadFile'], ['as' => $this->mailData['fileName'], 'mime' => $this->mailData['mimeType']])
    }

    return $mail;
}
```